# What's the syntax to run an executable from an html page in a browser?

Tags: language-agnostic

Of course the page will be on my pc not from a remote server. I just want to create a launch page for my most used software. I find windows program start menu too much a hassle and cannot find any freeware that does really a good job.

Don't tell it's not possible because I had already done this in the past with javascript referencing a file:/// but I don't remember what's the exact syntax.

Will it work in Google Chrome ?

Comment: If you're having trouble launching your applications, have you tried putting icons on your desktop? That vast expanse of space is there for a reason.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `file:///`, then the browser will download the file. Even IE's option of "running" the file is really just downloading it to a temp directory first, then running it. So no browser truly just runs an exe, as browsers weren't designed with that in mind.

You could run a local web server with a little bit of code that does "when user clicks this link, run this program". It would be the web server running the program, not the browser, but it'd have the same effect.

Comment: JavaScript is sandboxed away from your file system (at least, it was until recently. HTML5 is changing this). So it probably won't have much luck either, I hate to say. What is your real goal? Maybe there is another approach.